# Can't get excel macro to return after a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a little code that deletes an entire row when certain text is written in a cell.

```
Sub Delete_Rows()
For Each c In Range("B1:B20").Cells
    If c.Value = "text" Then
        c.EntireRow.Delete
    End If 
Next c
End Sub
```

This is what I wrote in my excel sheet

[image: excel sheet]

The problem is when I run it and the condition to delete a cell is met, excel automatically scrolls to the next row without evaluating the current cell, it skips like this

[image]

I run it again and only "text" from numbers 4 and 9 remain

After I run it a third time it finally deletes every cell with "text" written in it.

I tried to use a while loop instead, offset the selection, use an integer to subtract the loop iteration and several other ways and have had no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Two options are:

1. delete from the bottom up, or
2. delete all relevant rows at once (shown below):

---

```
Sub Delete_Rows()
    Dim deleteRange As Range
    For Each c In Range("B1:B20")
        If c.Value = "text" Then
            If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set deleteRange = c
            Else
                Set deleteRange = Union(c, deleteRange)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```